# Linux printing from Windows stopped working after upgrade to Windows 7: "Unknown error condition in stat: Function not implemented"

Tags: linux, windows-7, redhat, file-sharing, printing

my name is Justin and i am not a linux guy I do not know much about it only windows.
 We're a company and we're having troubles with printing and sharing from linux to Windows 7. I can connect to linux from windows 7 pc though.

What we have is Fedora Core 2.x.x(2003), Redhat 3.2.3, jBase
Currently we have at minimum 8 pc's (windows xp) connected to the linux machine for our server, it prints and sends to linux and linux connects back to the windows pc and prints what is requested.

After upgrading the pc's to windows 7 this no longer works. I've set up the pc with the same username, the computer name is different (windows 7 dont allow the same as Username), and same printer name.

Ive accessed /etc/nsswitch.conf and added wins before dns. Still no luck. Tryed disabling firewalls and all settings on win7 pc still no luck.

If i goto the linux machine and browse SAMBA Network i see the computer but when trying to access it I get an error: "Unknown error condition in stat: Function not implemented".
At first I had password protected file sharing and it would ask for User and Password. I'd enter it from linux and it'd give me the same error.

Not sure what to do here. Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade the ancient Linux machine as well. That hasn't been supported in almost a decade!

Answer (score 0):

There have been many changes in file sharing (SMB) from XP to Vista/7, one of them being on the authentication method.

You could try making the Win7 machines go back to using NTLMv1 (Google "windows 7 NTLMv1") but this is a bad idea.

You have an environment that is outdated beyond imagination. I would not even think about fixing ANYTHING in it, sincerely.

To get you started on the Right Path (TM), start studying the implementation of [CentOS 7](http://centos.org/) to replace both Fedora/RedHat, preferibly on a new machine. Transferring the old files and setting up file sharing will be a piece of cake (relatively speaking).

That being said, I'm not familiar with jBase and it looks like legacy software. Contact the vendor to check if they support a newer Linux distribution. If not, I would consider migrating from it (and hiring a dedicated sysadmin or contracting with a service provider to maintain your servers).

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but try this:

Go to: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy
Select: Local Policies -> Security Options

There are two settings to change.
"Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" -> Send LM & NTLM responses
"Minimum session security for NTLM SSP" -> uncheck: Require 128-bit encryption

source: http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/windows/article.php/3849061/Use-Samba-With-Windows-7-Clients.htm
which I found from this post that may also be helpful for you, https://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-43698.html

Comment: I think ive already done that not sure as i dont have Win7 Prem. I Have Home edition so no policy editor.